# What insect/invertebrate species evolves fastest?

Tags: evolution, experimental-design, ecosystem

I am starting an experiment in which I will be forcing evolution in a moderately complex species of insect or invertebrate. I am prepared for the possible longevity of this experiment, but i have no clue what species i should use. I would prefer a species that can easily respond to biotic challengers. Reason being, every abiotic factor will be promoting the growth and prosperity of the target species, however every biotic factor will be trying to kill the target species. The species can be aquatic, amphibious or terrestrial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Drosophila melanogaster.** (fruit-fly, pomice-fly)

[image: Flies with various eye colours.]

<sup>Image, public domain, [via Wikipedia 2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:EyeColors.jpg).</sup>

Development time is under ideal conditions 8.5 days (at 25 Celsius, 77 Fahrenheit), the females produce perhaps 500 eggs per generation which can hatch in 12-15 hours - from the point of view of turnover, you should be able to observe many generations in a short-ish period at one generation per ten days in reasonable conditions.

Their diet is fruit, fungi - both preferably decomposing and are able to be anaesthetised with ether or carbon dioxide.

They have acted as a [model organism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drosophila_melanogaster#Model_organism_in_genetics) (eukaryote) for the study of genetics and there are [many known mutations](https://academic.oup.com/genetics/article/201/3/815/5930114), and established ways to produce them (ethyl methane sulfonate, ionising radiation).

Comment: A classic example

Comment: Thank you very much, you gave me all the info I needed.

Comment: @Astrophysicsteen You're welcome. Feel free to "click the tick" if you find this appropriate as an accepted answer.